# Spring is flattening 2D JSON array to 1D String array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, spring

I'm using AJAX to post form data to a Spring controller. I append a 2D array to my form data like `data.push({name: "currentRoles", value: optionsArray});` and try to receive it as `Map<String, String>` however I get the error `Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]'`. For some reason the array seems to be getting flattened into a 1D array. The array is of the form: `{name: "currentRoles", value: Array(2)}`.

Full JS:

```
var roles = $(".selectpicker.role");
            var optionsArray = [];
            $.each(roles, function(index, item){
                var testArray = [];
               $.each($(roles[index]).find("option:selected"), function(index2, item2){
                  testArray.push($(item2).val());
               });
               optionsArray.push(testArray);"name":"currentRoles"}).val(optionsArray);
            });
            data.push({name: "currentRoles", value: optionsArray});
```

Edit: tried changing `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>`, no difference made

My controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/AdminEditGroup")
    public ModelAndView editGroup(@RequestParam String groupName, @RequestParam (required = false) String[] currentMembers,
                          @RequestParam (required = false) String currentFramework, @RequestParam (required = false) RoleWrapper currentRoles,
                                  @RequestParam String originalName, Model model){}
```

RoleWrapper:

```
public class RoleWrapper {

    private Map<String, Object> roleWrapper = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getRoleWrapper() {
        return roleWrapper;
    }

    public void setRoleWrapper(Map<String, Object> roleWrapper) {
        this.roleWrapper = roleWrapper;
    }
}
```

Edit: As an extension of Andreas' answer, I have changed my controller method to the following:

```
@PostMapping(value="/AdminEditGroup", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        public ModelAndView editGroup(@RequestParam MultiValueMap request, Model model){
        logger.info(request.toString());
}
```

This in turn produces the output: `currentRoles=[Student, Teacher, Student, Student,Teacher,Student]` for the JSON

```
{
  "name": "currentRoles",
  "value": [
    ["Student", "Teacher"],
    ["Student"]
  ]
}
```

The information is duplicated and again flattened into a 1D array. I suspect this is something to do with how Spring is converting form data.

Comment: Why did you believe that a 2D array, or any array for that matter, would map into a `String`? If you want help with your Java+Spring code, show the code, at least the handler method in question.

Comment: When ajax passes an array to spring it becomes string does it not? all my 1d JSON arrays gets mapped into String[] arrays

Comment: Ok, I will repeat: **Show the code**. We need to see how you defined the Spring handler method, so **edit** the question and show us the code!!

Comment: Honestly not sure what you're meaning by Spring handler code, I've already added the wrapper object and the controller

Comment: Wasn't there when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending JSON that potentially looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "currentRoles",
  "value": [
    ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    ["val4", "val5"],
    ["val6", "val7", "val8", "val9"]
  ]
}
```

To receive that kind of payload, you need to define the method as:

```java
@PostMapping(value="/AdminEditGroup", consumes="application/json")
public ModelAndView editGroup(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request, Model model) {
    String name = (String) request.get("name");
    List<List<String>> = (List) request.get("value");
    // code
}
```

Unless of course you are wrapping the `data` shown in the question code in something more complex, but since you haven't shared that, we can't help with that.

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to the duplicate the array information and squish it into a 1D array

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Map<String, Object>` this should be working fine. Your `value` is an array but you're trying to put that in String and that can't be done.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference, the error remains the same